# LocalStorage is cleared after running yarn build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a React app and I am saving some simple data to LocalStorage. All works well across refreshes, etc.
But when I run yarn build to refresh the built web after pushing a change, this will clear somehow the local storage.

I have a server setup with nginx and a reverse proxy, my web app being served through pm2.

Is this something expected to happen? Why does it happen and can it be avoided?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you have some more info about the context of your specific situation? i.e. are you able to post code snippets that show things like... your yarn build script, places in your code that interact with LocalStorage, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you use yarn to run your code on browser it basically create a fresh session on browser on every refresh. therefore you loosing your data.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Actually, using npm run build instead of using yarn build fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aslam_khan reply I found the solution:

Use npm run build instead of yarn build if you want to prevent LocalStorage to be cleared up on every new build.